# Strange Wick rotation in the computation of string partition function

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, integration, partition-function, wick-rotation

In order to compute the one-loop vacuum-to-vacuum amplitude for the bosonic string, one runs into
\begin{equation}
Z(\tau) = V_D (q \bar{q})^{-D/24} \int \frac{d^Dk}{(2 \pi)^D} \exp({- \pi \alpha^\prime \tau_2 k^2}) \prod_{n,\mu} \sum_{N_{\mu n},\tilde{N}_{\mu n}=0}^\infty q^{n N_{\mu n}} \bar{q}^{n N_{\mu n}}
\tag{7.2.6}\end{equation}
from the matter part of the theory (the $X^\mu$ fields) at a given modulus $\tau = \tau_1 + i\tau_2$, where $q=\exp(2 \pi i \tau)$. The expression above is equation (7.2.6) from Polchinski volume 1. This question concerns only the integral over the momenta. It is given by
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk^0}{2 \pi} \exp(\pi \alpha^\prime \tau_2 (k^0)^2) \,  \int \frac{d^{D-1}k}{(2 \pi)^{D-1}} \exp(-\pi \alpha^\prime \tau_2 (k^i)^2).
\end{equation}
How should the integral over $k^0$ be handled? Polchinski simply Wick-rotates $k^0 \to i k^D$, but usually Wick rotations are related to specific contour deformations which depend on the function $f(z)$ being integrated over the real line going to zero for $|z| \to \infty$. This is clearly not the case here, so the usual argument does not seem to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Eq. (7.2.6) has an Euclidean worldsheet (WS) and a Minkowskian target space (TS).

Perhaps the simplest is to instead start with the paradigm that the partition function $Z(\tau)$ should be mathematically well-defined and finite in the doubly Euclidean signature of the WS and TS, and then work our way backwards to the Minkowski formulation via [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) of WS and TS by inserting pertinent Feynman $i\epsilon$ prescriptions (or generalizations thereof) in appropriate places.

E.g. if we start from the Euclidean integration contour $k^D\in\mathbb{R}$ along the real $k^D$-axis, as a first step in the Wick rotation, the Minkowskian integration contour $k^0=ik^D\in i\mathbb{R}$ is along the imaginary $k^0$-axis. The next step would be to investigate whether it is possible to deform the Minkowskian $k^0$-integration contour.

Short of this exercise the conclusion is clear, though: The only tangible effect on the resulting $Z(\tau)$ formula (7.2.8) will be an $i$ from the integration measure $\mathrm{d}k^0=i\mathrm{d}k^D$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Starting with the Euclidean TS version of (7.2.6) and then setting $k^D = -i k^0$ gives us the divergent integral again, so I don't see what that would accomplish (unless there is a clever contour trick that allows us to do the integral starting from the Euclidean case). I agree that the Euclidean TS partition function is well defined, but some analytical continuation to the Minkowski case must exist.

Also, the insertion of $i \epsilon$ factors is usually meant to shift poles in order to enforce boundary conditions. In this case, the integrand has no poles at all.

Comment: I updated the answer.